# Enumerate all forms in VB.NET project, then show them by Name or Fullname?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

How do I create a reference to a form, simply by its Name or .Fullname..? It seems so simple, but nothing I've tried will work.

Given the following code, the part at the end is where I'm stuck.

Thanks.

```
Public Class frmLauncher

Private Sub FormPicker_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly =  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim myTypes() As Type = Nothing

    ' Both of the following lines seem to do the same thing.
    ' Is one way better or safer than the other? 
    myTypes = myAssembly.DefinedTypes
    myTypes = myAssembly.GetTypes

    For Each t In myTypes
        If t.BaseType.FullName.ToString.ToUpper = "System.Windows.Forms.Form".ToUpper Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(t.Name)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick

    Dim frmName As String = ListBox1.Text

    ' the next line is where I'm totally stuck.
    Dim frm As Form = GetSomethingUnknown(frmName)  

    frm.Show()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: A form is just a class, so you wouldn't and couldn't create a reference to it, but you could create a reference to an instance (object) created from that class.  I would stay away from Reflection for now.  First, it is pretty complex and you dont want to risk it seeming like the solution to every situation you encounter.

Comment: Once I had the list of forms I'd just use the list to generate code to load the forms - OK for quick and dirty, not dynamic of course. Look for NimbleText for an interesting tool for building repetitive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an instance of your forms first add to your listbox the FullName property, this includes also the namespace of your own application and it is required to find the form classes via reflection

```
For Each t In myTypes
    If t.BaseType.FullName.ToString.ToUpper = "System.Windows.Forms.Form".ToUpper Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(t.FullName)
    End If
Next
```

Now the code required to create the instance is the following

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DoubleClick

    Dim frmName As String = ListBox1.Text

    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim obj = myAssembly.GetType(frmName).InvokeMember(Nothing, Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim frm As Form = CType(obj, System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

As you can see, the crucial point here is the [call to InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx) method from the type identified by your frmName variable. This is a complex method that you should study carefully if you want really work with reflection code.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. As I indicated, I assumed something like that had to happen, such as GetMethod, etc, but I had no idea what. I've looked up InvokeMember and yes...I have some more learning to do. I'm going to put in some Breakpoints and nose around.

I have a couple followup questions...

1) In VBA, the type 'Variant' is the catch-all for everything. Is that how 'obj' is working in this instance? No type is defined.

2) Which of these lines of code from my example would be preferred?

myTypes = myAssembly.DefinedTypes
myTypes = myAssembly.GetTypes

Comment: Sorry, I see the HTML editor didn't format any of my comment above well. I hope you can make it out ok. Thanks..!!

Comment: DefinedTypes is an IEnumerable<TypeInfo> while GetTypes returns an array of types. There is a difference between the twos. The first one, being an IEnumerable, allows you to start the loop immediately, the second one requires you to wait it finish build the whole array in memory. In your context, DefinedTypes is better but, if this is a deal maker, depends on how many types are present in the assembly. Object vs Variant, I am not an expert on this matter but while they are not exactly the same, for general purpose tasks, I think you could equiparate the two

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. If it was a huge project, GetTypes() could take a while.